# Write my own version of DebugView

Tags: c++, debugging, drive, windows-kernel, windows-dev-center

I wrote a Windows driver (file system). All my logs print by the DbgPrint function. With the [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) program (*Capture Kernel* - on) I can see all my logs.

I want to show/save its logs. So, I want to listen to kernel messages.

I tried to write some:

```
struct DbWinBuffer
{
    DWORD dwProcessId;
    char data[4096 - sizeof(DWORD)];
};

DbWinBuffer* dbBuffer;

HANDLE hAckEvent;
HANDLE hEvent;
HANDLE hSharedFile;

SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;

sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sa.bInheritHandle = true;
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = &sd;

if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
{
    printf("ERROR: InitializeSecurityDescriptor\\n");
    return 1;
}

if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, true, 0, false))
{
    printf("ERROR: SetSecurityDescriptorDacl\n");
    return 1;
}

hAckEvent = CreateEvent(&sa, false, false, L"DBWIN_BUFFER_READY");
if (!hAckEvent)
{
    printf("ERROR: CreateEvent(\\"DBWIN_BUFFER_READY\\")\\n");
    return 1;
}

hEvent = CreateEvent(&sa, false, false, L"DBWIN_DATA_READY");
if (!hEvent)
{
    printf("ERROR: CreateEvent(\\"DBWIN_DATA_READY\\")\\n");
    return 1;
}

hSharedFile = CreateFileMapping((HANDLE)-1, &sa, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 4096, L"DBWIN_BUFFER");
if (!hSharedFile)
{
    printf("ERROR: CreateFileMapping(\\"DBWIN_BUFFER\\")\\n");
    return 1;
}

dbBuffer = static_cast<DbWinBuffer*>(MapViewOfFile(hSharedFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 4096));
if (!dbBuffer)
{
    printf("ERROR: MapViewOfFile\\n");
    return 1;
}

SetEvent(hAckEvent);

DWORD pid = GetCurrentProcessId();
printf("Tracing PID: %dnn", pid);

for (;;)
{
    DWORD ret = WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
    if (ret == WAIT_FAILED)
    {
        printf("ERROR: WaitForSingleObject\\n");
        return 1;
    }
    SetEvent(hAckEvent);
}
```

In this example I get only OutputDebugString, not the DbgPrint. How can I get DbgPrint messages?

Comment: you need call [DbgSetDebugPrintCallback](http://www.ntsecurity.nu/onmymind/2006/2006-06-12.html)

Comment: Where should I set it function? in the driver? or in the separate program?

Comment: of course in the driver. this is kernel mode api, exported from `ntoskrnl.exe` (`ntoskrnl.lib`)

Comment: In case that i want a separate program, like dbgview, how can I do it?

Comment: you need driver for setup own callback with `DbgSetDebugPrintCallback` and user mode application, which will be communicate with driver and got strings from it. this is exactly what `dbgview.exe` doing - it using driver `dbgv.sys`